# Breadcrumbs RDFA

Tags: rich-snippets, breadcrumbs, rdfa

Have implemented Breadcrumb RDFA

```
 http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=sellcar&Itemid=4
```

While checking the page , the RDFA Data shows property: title:  Home

```
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycarhelpline.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_forms%26view%3Dpages%26layout%3Dsellcar%26Itemid%3D4
```

However, when i compare ours with others

```
 http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Froyalenfield.com%2Fmotorcycles%2Fthunderbird-500%2F
```

The **Title and Description** of the current page is shown in every RDFA Data, which is not shown in ours

If someone could suggest - how to get the page title and description show up in RDFA Data, below is our breadcrumb code

```
  <p><span class="breadcrumbs pathway">
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
     <a href="" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a> &raquo;
        <span rel="v:child">
         <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
         <a href="index.php?option=com_forms&view=pages&layout=selloldcarindelhi&Itemid=4" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Sell Car</a> &raquo;
             <span rel="v:child">
                 <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                     <a property="v:title" >Sell Used Car</a>
                     </span>
             </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct as breadcrumbs are no started showing in Google Search results
For anyone using this - may ignore `<span class="breadcrumbs pathway">` and use his styling class and rest may only change the domain URL and breadcrumb title.